# How do I set my picturebox (bullets in my case) on their own axis seperate from my character's movement in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm very, VERY, new to coding and started a class in Visual Studio and the language Visual Basic in a .NET windows form app. So on that note, please cut me some slack.
I am trying to make a little game where you can move your character and shoot a monster or two in only 4 directions (left, right, up, left). Well, the problem is that my bullets move when I try to move my character with the WASD keys. This is most likely because I have set my WASD keys to both movements for the movement of the character, and the direction in which the bullets (PictureBox) shoots. I've tried making boolean switches, but me being new to coding seems to have caused some trouble figuring it out. I'll drop what I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Health As Integer = 7
Dim UUp As Boolean = True
Dim UDown As Boolean = True
Dim ULeft As Boolean = True
Dim URight As Boolean = True
Dim EUp As Boolean = True
Dim EDown As Boolean = True
Dim ELeft As Boolean = True
Dim ERight As Boolean = True
Dim Bullets(-1) As Bullet
Dim intCount As Integer
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    'movement of character player controls
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.W And UUp = True) Then
        pbIssac.Top -= 5
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.A And ULeft = True) Then
        pbIssac.Left -= 5
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.D And URight = True) Then
        pbIssac.Left += 5
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.S And UDown = True) Then
        pbIssac.Top += 5
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape) Then
        End
    End If
    'creation of bullet? code from internet!
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Space
            ReDim Preserve Bullets(intCount)
            Dim bullet1 As New Bullets
            Controls.Add(bullet1)
            Bullets(intCount) = bullet1
            intCount += 1
            tmrShoot.Enabled = True
    End Select

    'direction character is facing determines direction of bullet
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A) Then
        My.Settings.Keypressed = 1
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.D) Then
        My.Settings.Keypressed = 2
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.W) Then
        My.Settings.Keypressed = 3
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.S) Then
        My.Settings.Keypressed = 4
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
```

Bullet Class (From the internet!)

```
Public Class Bullet
Inherits PictureBox
Public Sub New()
    With Me
        .Size = New Size(10, 30)
        .Location = Form1.pbIssac.Location
        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
        .BackgroundImage = My.Resources.green
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Shoot()
    If (My.Settings.Keypressed = 1) Then
        Me.Left -= 3
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf (My.Settings.Keypressed = 2) Then
        Me.Left += 3
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf (My.Settings.Keypressed = 3) Then
        Me.Top -= 3
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf (My.Settings.Keypressed = 4) Then
        Me.Top += 4
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using `My.Settings` like that. The purpose of `My.Settings` is to persist data between when you exit the app and when you start it again. If you want to store data during a session then just use appropriate variables.

Comment: As for your issue, you would need to modify the `Bullet` class so that it knows what the current direction was when it was shot. You should be passing in the current location and current direction when invoking the constructor.  The class then uses the provided location instead of getting it from a form that it should know nothing about, and it stores the direction to use each time it moves.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you very much! My only problem, however, is that I'm not sure what you mean by me passing the current location and current direction when invoking the constructor. May I have an explanation?

Comment: A constructor is just a method that gets invoked when you create an instance of a type. Like any other method, it can have parameters. Like any other method, you pass arguments to those parameters when you invoke it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I apologize for being very unknowledgeable about coding, but I am still trying to figure out how I should create what you meant. Is there any way you could show me an example relative to my code? if not that's fine as well, I am just currently stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that I would do in that situation:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private characterPosition As Point

    'Set a default direction for the character.
    Private characterDirection As Direction = Direction.Up

    Private ReadOnly bullets As New List(Of Bullet)

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.W
                characterDirection = Direction.Up
                'Move character up.
            Case Keys.S
                characterDirection = Direction.Down
                'Move character down.
            Case Keys.A
                characterDirection = Direction.Left
                'Move character left.
            Case Keys.D
                characterDirection = Direction.Right
                'Move character right.
            Case Keys.Space
                bullets.Add(New Bullet(characterPosition, characterDirection))
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class


Public Enum Direction
    Up
    Down
    Left
    Right
End Enum


Public Class Bullet

    Private direction As Direction

    Public Sub New(location As Point, direction As Direction)
        '...
        Me.direction = direction
    End Sub

    Public Sub Move()
        Select Case direction
            Case Direction.Up
                'Move bullet up.
            Case Direction.Down
                'Move bullet down.
            Case Direction.Left
                'Move bullet left.
            Case Direction.Right
                'Move bullet right.
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that each bullet remembers its own direction so you just tell it to move and it moves.